# How to implement the SVG <use> element to clone graphics?

Tags: svg, optimization

I am attempting to minimize the size of SVG files by use of the `<use>` element, but I am not having any luck. Attempts to clone a simple circle have failed:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   height="102.24211"
   width="217.88487"
   fill="#000000"
   viewBox="0 0 196.09639 92.048573"
   x="0px"
   y="0px"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg42"
   sodipodi:docname="mandala_01.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.2.1 (9c6d41e410, 2022-07-14)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
  <defs
     id="defs46" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview44"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="2.0725"
     inkscape:cx="47.768396"
     inkscape:cy="75.271411"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1009"
     inkscape:window-x="1912"
     inkscape:window-y="1072"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg42" />
  <title
     id="title2">Asset 2</title>
  <metadata
     id="metadata286">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:title>Asset 2</dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <circle
     style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel"
     id="path396"
     cx="31"
     cy="31"
     r="29" />
  <use href="#path396" id="u1" x="60" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```

Perhaps I am referencing the incorrect id, but I don't think that's the issue? I'll admit right up front that I simply created the `id="u1"` tag in imitation of an example I found online. Insight greatly appreciated.

Comment: I see two circles, the original and the use element copy. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: When I open the file in Inkscape I only see the one circle. I opened it in Chrome and the second circle displayed correctly. Now I don't know if I'm more or less confused than when I began. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps Inkscape is buggy. You could try reporting it to their bugtracker and see where it gets you.

Comment: For Inkscape, you'll have to use `xlink:href` instead of `href`. You should then add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to the root element.

Comment: Thanks a ton @ccprog! That is some excellent info.